# wordpress omits width and height declaration on some product images, not others

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I have an odd problem with woocommerce product images sometimes omitting the width and height declaration as you can see on https://www.tidybedrooms.co.uk/product-category/hinged-door-wardrobes/.

Looking at the top row of images on that page you will see that the 1st, 2nd and 4th images are displayed mush larger than the 3rd and 5th. The images i have uploaded to WP are all the same dimensions, and the only distinction i can make when viewing source of the correct vs oversized images is that the oversized images omit a tage for width and height, where the correct images do not.

Has anyone experienced this issue, or know how i can resolve it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that for some reason, the larger images are being displayed as base64 data instead of URLs by default. It is interesting that occurred. Perhaps you can work out why by retracing the steps you used to insert the images for these products vs the others.

As for a quick fix, you can add the following to the theme's custom stylesheet:

```
.attachment-shop_single {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, ideally i'd like to know whats going within wocommerce to trigger it. i have deleted and readded products using exactly the same procedure and it sometimes works correctly initially but over time reverts back to oversizing the images. I have recently added google's pagespeed program and im wondering if its something to do with that

Comment: Sounds like you might be on to something there. If the google's pagespeed program is implemented via a plugin, you can deactivate it, clear cache if enabled and check. Except your site is live, so unless necessary, maybe best test the plugin with a development copy of your site.